# Why is $\sum_{i=1}^n |v_i| || Le_i||_W \leq \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} ||Le_j||_W \sum_{i=1}^n ||v||_1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Why is $\sum_{i=1}^n |v_i| || Le_i||_W \leq \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} ||Le_j||_W \sum_{i=1}^n ||v||_1$?

Where $v_i$ is a scalar taken by linearity out of $\sum_i Lv_ie_i$, $e_i$s are standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and  $L: V \rightarrow W$ linear transformation. $V$ is finite normed space, $W$ is normed space.

For a basis $\{ f_i \}$ the norm
$||\sum v_i f_i||_1=||(v_1,v_2,..., v_n)||_1$ and is an isometry between $(\mathbb{R}^n, ||\cdot||_1)$ and $(V, ||\cdot||_1)$.

I have troubles reading the inequality. I'm not really sure what happens in it. Does it use Cauchy-Schwartz?

Why can one assume that $\sum_{i=1}^n ||Le_i||_w \leq \max_j ||Le_j||_W$?

What about the inequality applied on $\sum_{i=1}^n |v_i|$? Is this a $\ell^p$-space?

Comment: In term of functional spaces this is the Holder inequality with $l^1$ and $l^\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n |v_i| || Le_i||_W &\le \sum_{i=1}^n |v_i| \left(\max_{1 \leq j \leq n} ||Le_j||_W\right) \\
&= \left(\max_{1 \leq j \leq n} ||Le_j||_W\right) \sum_{i=1}^n |v_i| \\
&= \left(\max_{1 \leq j \leq n} ||Le_j||_W\right) ||v||_1 \\
&\le \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} ||Le_j||_W \sum_{i=1}^n ||v||_1
\end{align}

Comment: Why can one assume that $\sum_{i=1}^n ||Le_i||_W \leq \max_j ||Le_j||_W$?

Comment: @mavavilj No, you can't.  Consider $L(x,y) = x + y$.  $||L(1,1)|| = \sqrt2 > \max\{L(0,1),L(1,0)\}$.

Comment: Then why do you make that statement then?

Comment: @mavavilj $$||Le_i||_W \le \max_j ||Le_j||_W$$

Comment: But the LHS has sum over $i$? So it's $\sum_{i=1}^n ||Le_i||_W$?

Comment: @mavavilj $$\forall i \in \{1,\dots,n\}, ||Le_i||_W \le \max_{j \in \{1,\dots,n\}} ||Le_j||_W$$

Comment: Okay now I understand, so it's treated as a sort of constant that's carried over the sum.

Comment: @mavavilj Bingo, for each $i$, we bound $||Le_i||$ by $C = \max_{j \in \{1,\dots,n\}} ||Le_j||_W$ independent of $i$, so that we can take it out of the summation sign.